# What are the extra peers.dat files?

Tags: bitcoin-core, peers

I am restarting my bitcoin node. I noticed there are more than one `peers.dat` files, and many don't end in `.dat`. Should these be deleted? Is my node compromised? Any explanation is appreciated. Thank you!

[image: .bitcoin directory contents]